# Quick navigate to the definition code of a function from another ruby gem in Emacs using ctags

Tags: ruby, emacs, ctags

I have a ruby script in emacs.

```
require 'watir'
ie=Watir::IE.new
```

When I puts the cursor on the word IE and press C+] , I want Emacs to open the definition of the IE class, which is in the source code of the watir gem.

How can I achieve that using Emacs and ctags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following command it the directory where your gems are installed:

```
ctags -e -a --Ruby-kinds=-fF -o TAGS -R .
```

Afterwards press <kbd>M-.</kbd> in Emacs while your cursor is over the `Watir` word. Emacs will prompt you for the location of the TAGS file and afterwards it will jump to the definition of the type.

Basic etags usage in Emacs:

<kbd>M-.</kbd> goes to the method under the cur­sor, in the same win­dow. First time it asks for the TAGS file.
<kbd>C-4 .</kbd> goes to the method under the cur­sor. Opens a new win­dow. First time it asks for the TAGS file.
<kbd>M-,</kbd> cycles to the next selection.